# Cannot change "w32tm /query /source" from "Local CMOS Clock" on PDC Domain Controller

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller, ntp, w32time

I am trying to reconfigure the time settings for a single DC W2K8R2 domain. The DC is not a VM.

I followed the instructions on this page to the letter.....

https://gooroo.io/GoorooTHINK/Article/17139/Configuring-Time-Settings-on-Domain-Controllers/26731

That involved running...

```
net stop w32time
w32tm /configure /syncfromflags:manual /manualpeerlist:"0.us.pool.ntp.org,0x1 1.us.pool.ntp.org,0x1 2.us.pool.ntp.org,0x1 3.us.pool.ntp.org,0x1"
net start w32time
w32tm /configure /reliable:yes /update
w32tm /resync
```

All seems to go fine except the last command, which returns.....

```
The computer did not resync because no time data was available.
```

Yet whenever I run.....

```
"w32tm /query /source"
```

I get "Local CMOS Clock" instead of the desired NTP servers.

When I navigate the registry to *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\w32time\Parameters* the *Type* key is set to "NTP" as expected, and the *NtpServer* key is set to.....

```
"0.us.pool.ntp.org,0x1 1.us.pool.ntp.org,0x1 2.us.pool.ntp.org,0x1 3.us.pool.ntp.org,0x1"
```

Any idea what could be going on here?

EDIT: The output of "w32tm /query /configuration" is.....

```
[Configuration]
EventLogFlags: 2 (Policy)   
AnnounceFlags: 10 (Policy)
TimeJumpAuditOffset: 28800 (Local)
MinPollInterval: 6 (Policy)
MaxPollInterval: 10 (Policy)
MaxNegPhaseCorrection: 172800 (Policy)
MaxPosPhaseCorrection: 172800 (Policy)
MaxAllowedPhaseOffset: 300 (Policy)
FrequencyCorrectRate: 4 (Policy)
PollAdjustFactor: 5 (Policy)
LargePhaseOffset: 50000000 (Policy)
SpikeWatchPeriod: 900 (Policy)
LocalClockDispersion: 10 (Policy)
HoldPeriod: 5 (Policy)
PhaseCorrectRate: 1 (Policy)
UpdateInterval: 100 (Policy)


[TimeProviders]
NtpClient (Local)
DllName: C:\Windows\system32\w32time.DLL (Local)
Enabled: 1 (Local)
InputProvider: 1 (Local)
CrossSiteSyncFlags: 2 (Policy)
AllowNonstandardModeCombinations: 1 (Local)
ResolvePeerBackoffMinutes: 15 (Policy)
ResolvePeerBackoffMaxTimes: 7 (Policy)
CompatibilityFlags: 2147483648 (Local)
EventLogFlags: 0 (Policy)
LargeSampleSkew: 3 (Local)
SpecialPollInterval: 3600 (Policy)
Type: NT5DS (Policy)
NtpServer (Local)
DllName: C:\Windows\system32\w32time.DLL (Local)
Enabled: 1 (Local)
InputProvider: 0 (Local)
AllowNonstandardModeCombinations: 1 (Local)
VMICTimeProvider (Local)
DllName: C:\Windows\System32\vmictimeprovider.dll (Local)
Enabled: 1 (Local)
InputProvider: 1 (Local)
```

Comment: What does `w32tm /query /configuration` show?

Comment: Thanks joeqwerty. I have updated my original question with the output of w32tm /query /configuration.

Comment: Have you checked that you have network connectivity to the NTP servers in question?

Comment: The output of your `w32tm /query /configuration` shows that the Windows Time service settings are being managed by Group Policy. You need to make your desired changes in the GPO that's being used to configure the Windows Time service.

Comment: I've seen this a few times where a Group Policy Object with a WMI filter is used to configure the Windows Time service on the DC that holds the PDCe FSMO role. This ensures that if you move the PDCe FSMO role to another server you won't have to manually reconfigure the Windows Time service.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. This was the correct answer. If you post it again as an answer I'll gladly accept it as the solution.